# Django and react images don't appear with media folder

Tags: reactjs, django

I use django rest framework and react where I am trying to show a user's profile picture by fetching them with axios in react.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static')
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static/media')
```

When I save a user's profile picture from admin panel the image is added in media folder. React is inside django.

I use build in react and the structure looks like this.

- **build**

  - **static**

    - **media**

      - **images**
- **src**
- **public**

In the django rest framework page the image looks like this `/media/images/Photo.jpg`

The problem is that even when I open the image from the admin panel it doesn't show and instead shows this [image]

Also in the frontend it doesn't appear.

```
const profiles = friends.map(friend => {
        return (
            <>
                <img src={friend.profile.profile_pic} />
            </>
        )
    })
```